# How would i loop this bit of code so that It will go to the start again?

Tags: python

I'm a new to python and i need a bit of help. I just need to know how would i loop this bit of code so that after it says "please try again..." it will then go onto "Do you want to roll or stick". Thanks in advance.

```
Roll = input("Do you want to Roll or Stick?")
if Roll in ("Roll" , "roll"):
    print("Your new numbers are," , +number10 , +number20 , +number30 , +number40 , +number50)
if Roll in ("Stick" , "stick"):
    print("Your numbers are," , +number1 , +number2 , +number3 , +number4 , +number5)
else:
    print("Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap up your code with [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop:

```
while True:
    Roll = input("Do you want to Roll or Stick?")
    if Roll.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    ...
    else:
        print("Please try again. Type 'exit' to exit.")
```